# Getting 404 for ScriptBundle on remote IIS 7.5 server and localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, scriptbundle

I've configured bundles in ASP.NET BundleConfig.cs file.

```
ScriptBundle thirdPartyScripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js");
    thirdPartyScripts.Include(

    "~/js/flowtype.js",
    "~/js/moment.js",
    "~/js/livestamp.min.js",
    "~/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js",
    "~/js/jsSocials/jssocials.min.js",
    "~/js/SweetAlert/sweetalert.min.js"    
      );


 bundles.Add(thirdPartyScripts);
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

I get Error 404 (Not Found) for that same path.

Example of URL:

```
/bundles/js/?v=un_i2qaQ99Yn3-3GnBhE9kyHMvKZrbEB7nMRdO7cD-I1
```

Developing in ASP.NET 4.5 / C# / Web Project (Web Forms)

Comment: do you happen to have a folder named bundles inside your project?

Comment: @Robert No, This is the first thing I checked.

Comment: Try rename bundle to bundles/jsx. Maybe it conflicts with js folder

Comment: Have you tried loading the url in the browser, but without the trailing "/"?  /bundles/js?v=un_i2qaQ99Yn3-3GnBhE9kyHMvKZrbEB7nMRdO7cD-I1

Comment: @Robert correction, in localhost also doesn't work well. same problem as server. It was cached and I saw previous results.

Comment: Have you registered bundles on application start then? Inside global asax

Comment: @Robert I have a feeling that it has to do with the rewrite rules for the www to non-www. Checking it now.